# conv1d data_format deprecation warning

Tags: tensorflow

I have some TensorFlow code that looks like this:

```
input_layer = tf.reshape(X, [-1, length, channels])

conv1_filters = 10
conv1_kernel_size = 5
conv1 = tf.layers.conv1d(
    inputs=input_layer,
    filters=conv1_filters,
    kernel_size=conv1_kernel_size,
    padding='same',
    activation=tf.nn.relu,
    )
```

It actually works correctly, but with TF 1.6.0 it now gets a warning:

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\w\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py:497: calling conv1d (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) with data_format=NHWC is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
`NHWC` for data_format is deprecated, use `NWC` instead

Okay so maybe I ought to update my code. I tried adding a parameter to the conv1d call:

```
    data_format='NWC',
```

but that gets an error:

ValueError: The `data_format` argument must be one of "channels_first", "channels_last". Received: NWC

Okay, I tried doing as the error message said:

```
    data_format='channels_last',
```

But that gets the original deprecation warning.

Is there something else I should be doing, or should I just ignore the warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing and your question motivated me to look into this. Calling `tf.layers.conv1d` actually results in a long stream of convolution-related classes/methods being called (ops using ops using ops...).

To be precise (skip this if not interested):

- `layers.conv1d` uses `layers._Conv` (base class for all conv layers).
- `layers._Conv` calls `nn_ops.Convolution` as its `_convolution_op`.
- `nn_ops.Convolution` uses `_WithSpaceToBatch` as its `conv_op`.
- `_WithSpaceToBatch` gets `_NonAtrousConvolution` as its `build_op`.
- `_NonAtrousConvoluton` will (in the 1D case) use `conv1d` as its `conv_op` (to be precise it uses `self._conv1d` which calls `conv1d`). This is the `tf.nn.conv1d` which is of course very different from `tf.layers.conv1d` we called in the beginning.
- As noted, `tf.nn.conv1d` produces the deprecation warning.

I strongly suspect that somewhere along this chain, the conversion from the "user friendly" `channels_first/last` (used by the `tf.layers` interface) to the more generic format such as `NCHW/NHWC` (used by the lower-level ops) wasn't updated properly to using `NCW/NWC` for 1D convolutions.

The short and boring answer: [See this github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17842). Apparently this will *not* yet be fixed in TF 1.7.